# Where I can't create timer of EJB3 Timer Service?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.0, lifecycle, session-bean

In EJB3 Timer Service, I can create the timer with the `timerService.createTimer(...)`function, but the question is where I can use it?
As I know, I can't do it in Session Bean's lifecycle function, like `@PostConstruct` function.

I also read it can't be called in Stateful session bean?
Is there anything else I should pay attention about createing timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most important thing to be aware of is that timers are transactional objects; it means, if you create a timer in a transaction that will roll back, the timer creation will be rolled back as well. This also implies that they must be called in a transaction context, and there is none in `@PostConstruct`.

Oh, and as you know, you need a TimerService to create a timer, so you usually will be using it in managed classes, so you can inject it.

Comment: It's possible to call `timerService.createTimer(...)` in a `@PostConstruct` method of a `@Singleton` Session Bean if it implements `javax.ejb.TimedObject`. Is it bad to do so?

Comment: Sadly, I lost touch with Java EE years ago and don't know how to answer this.